# Visual Studio 2012: Syntax Highlighting is turning off and on

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm using VS2012 and I'm quite happy with it. But the problem is, whem I'm coding in C++, that the syntax highlighting is turning off an on all over again. Sometimes, the highlighting is off and I have to reload the file. Also, it highlighting is quite slow.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I'm also using VS 2012 (Version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3) and never had this problem. But lately I prefer using qtcreator for c++ (it can use msvc as a compiler).

Comment: For what it's worth, I haven't had such a problem with VS2012 either (also on Update 3).  Highlighter is pretty fast, even on large files.  Only problem such as this I've seen is with extensions (particularly a spell checker in certain scenarios).  You might try disabling all extensions to see if you can identify a troublesome one...

Answer (score 15):

I know this is a while ago but I have had this same problem appearing randomly until just now.

It would disable when the last line in a file was a single line comment. (// blah blah). As soon as i removed that the text highlighting worked again!

Comment: Yep, this did it for me.

Comment: Similar issue for me, but in my case it was a single line comment as the first line of a method body. It meant that syntax highlighting disappeared half way down the file.

Comment: I re-installed VS hoping it'd fix the flickering, but to no avail. Somehow this did the trick! Running VS 2012 Ultimate with all Productivity Tools features enabled.

Comment: This fixed it for me too.  Thanks @Kay

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** In this answer I assume that your problem description is correct. In other words, I'm assuming that occasionally C++ highlighting is working, and the other times the text appears as plain text: **completely black and white**.

My guess is you are using an extension which modifies or replaces the way Visual Studio highlights C++ code. Try temporarily disabling all of your extensions and checking again if the editor is working. Some extensions might have the Disable button disabled; in that case you'll need to uninstall the extension for this test (possibly through Control Panel → Programs and Features).

As an example of one common extension that completely replaces the C++ highlighter is Visual Assist. However, I do not personally use that product and I haven't heard of any specific problems with it of this nature. I am merely mentioning it as an example of an extension that completely changes the behavior of Visual Studio in regards to syntax highlighting of C++ code.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I have CodeMaid installed. Disabling the extension and restarting VS fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

For me, highlighting always stops working when the first visible line in the editor begins with the characters '//' and I trigger reparsing somehow (CTRL + S for instance).

Highlighting always works fine when the first visible line in the editor begins with anything else, even with a whitespace, and I trigger reparsing somehow.

I could indent all my comments and never experience this problem, but now that I know about it, it's not so annoying anymore, so I let it be.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Visual Studio 2012:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760154/syntax-highlighting-sometimes-not-working

Answer (score 1):

If you're using only Intellisense, you may go to *Edit->Intellisense->Toggle Completion Mode* (or hit *Ctrl + Alt + Space*), play with it and see if it works (maybe you've pressed this combination of keys by accident).

I've also installed Update 3 and haven't had any problems since. Who knows..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Disabling the extentions sadly did not work for me. 
After searching around and realizing that it only happened on larger files, 
I got it to work by turning harware acceleration off.

Tools->Options...->Environment->General 
*Automatically adjust [...] (off) 
*Use hardware graphics acceleration (off)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it turned out that a large block of code (a 200+ line method) was commented out with `//` starting in the first column, and this was causing the syntax coloring not to work.  I changed the commenting delineation to `/* ... */` for that method and all of the syntax coloring was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I found that things like:

```
#if 0// bla-bla
```

mess up syntax highlighting badly. The solution that works for is to put a space before a comment, like so:

```
#if 0 // bla-bla
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 yesterday and started experiencing the exact same behavior described in the original post.   Based on some suggestions in this thread, I took at look at my extensions, and disabling AllMargins fixed the issue.   I've since re-enabled AllMargins and everything appears to be working as it should.

Try disabling and re-enabling any of your extensions;  hopefully that will fix the issue for you.