# Visual Studio 2015 Syntax highlighting in C Project

Tags: c++, c, syntax, visual-studio-2015, highlighting

I've got a big problem with VS2015. In .c files or .cpp there aren't a syntax highlighting.

1. loaded settings from my friend -> didn't work
2. reinstalled -> didn't work
3. ask my Prof. -> he looked in my settings and haven't an idea because all is ok

Can you help me?
[It's like windows notepad.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QSSP.jpg)

edit: I updated VS2015 now and the syntax highlighting works. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992686/visual-studio-2012-syntax-highlighting-is-turning-off-and-on

Comment: I finally found a way to defeat automatic syntax highlighting in Notepad++. In the style configurator select "GUI4CLI" and add `c` as a user extension. Now only the comments are highlighted ;)

Answer (score 0):

Start VS2015 with command-line options /ResetUserData or /ResetSettings, e.g.:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /ResetUserData
```

and/or:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /ResetSettings
```

**Note:** You will lose all your user settings and recent projects/files list